# Env Vars is undefined in my seed.js file (NODEJS)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, environment-variables, dotenv, .env

I'm working on this project and everything is working fine, my .env is working and all the env variables is defined in variant files. Then I decided to make a seed file for my database, but it's not able to read the MONGODB_URL value from .env and its output is undefined. 
Although it's working from almost anywhere I use it (the same variable!)

I already configured .env in my app. 
 
 this is my server.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('dotenv').config()
require('./db/mongoose.js')

const cors = require("cors")
const express = require('express')
const userRouter = require('./routers/user.router')
const answerRouter = require('./routers/answer.router')
const questionRouter = require('./routers/question.router')

console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL) // works!
const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT // port = 5000

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(userRouter) 
app.use(questionRouter)
app.use(answerRouter)


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server is up on port: " + port) //server is up on port 5000
})
```

this is my .env

```
SERVER_PORT = 5000
MONGODB_URL='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/app0-dev-database'
```

this is my seed.js

```
const seeder = require('mongoose-seed');

console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL) // undefined
seeder.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, function(){ // error
    seeder.loadModels([
        './server/models/user.model.js',
        './server/models/question.model.js'
    ]);
    seeder.clearModels (['User','Question' ], function(){
        seeder.populateModels(data, function (err, done){
            if(err) {
                return console.log("seed err", err)
            }
            if (done) {
                return console.log("seed done", done);
            }
            seeder.disconnect()
        })
    })
})
```

[this is my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0PS4.png) 
the value of MONGODB_URL is undefined 
I need to know how to read its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If seed.js doesn't reqiure/load server.js in any way, you can't rely on the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) call there - you need to require it in both files. 
 In "seed.js" you should write the following:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: Oh that worked. it was so simple i didn't think of it. Thank you very much for your help